# Copying Only Directories With Files

Tags: shell, scripting, find, directory

I am trying to copy files and the directory it is in to another location. I can find the path like this:

```
find ~/dim_import/* -type f ! -name xdir | cut -d '/' -f 5-10
```

which outputs

```
general/header.txt
scripts/test
scripts/tt
```

How do I copy these to another location? For example the new location would be

```
new/general/header.txt
new/scripts/test
new/scripts/tt
```

The issue is that there are more directories that are empty and I do not want to copy those, only the directories that have files in them and the files themselves.

NOTE: **not using bash**, using `sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just writing to a file:

```
find ~/dim_import/* -type f ! -name xdir | cut -d '/' -f 5-6 > files
```

and then looping through the "files" file and creating the directories from that and then copying the files there.

```
while read line; do
  fileDir=`echo "$line" | cut -d '/' -f 1`    # get folder name
  fileName=`echo "$line" | cut -d '/' -f 2`   # get file name
  cd ~/"sr${srNum}"                           # go to SR folder

  # If proper directory doesn't exist, create
  if [ ! -d "$fileDir" ]; then 
    mkdir "$fileDir"
  fi

  # Copy file to respected directory
  cd $ROOT                                        # go back to dim_import
  cp "$fileDir/$fileName" ~/"sr$srNum/$fileDir"   # copy file to fileDir folder
  cd ~/"sr$srNum/$fileDir"                        # go to fileDir
  chmod u+w "$fileName"                  # mod the file for write access for changes
  cd $ROOT                                        # go back to dim_import
done < files
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that only uses `POSIX` shell features:

```
find ~/dim_import/* -type f ! -name xdir -exec sh -c '
  p=${1%/*}; 
  d=${p##*/}; 
  f=${1##*/}; 
  mkdir -p new/"$d"; 
  cp "$1" new/"$d"' -- {} \;
```

Comment: This fails. It outputs:
`cp: cannot access : No such file or directory`
`cp: cannot access : No such file or directory`
`cp: cannot access : No such file or directory`
So the mkdir command isn't working

Comment: I'm think the problem here is that you need to use 0 for every 1 ised in the answer (`$0` in a`sh -c` command is equivalent to `$1` in a shell script. I have no idea why that's the case).

Comment: @evilsoup in this case, $0 is `--`.

Answer (score 0):

xargs should be available. You could use:

```
find ~/dim_import/* -type f ! -name xdir | xargs -I {} cp {} new/{}
```

Comment: This will copy to `new/$HOME/dim_import/general/` and will only work if that path already exists. He just wants `new/general`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know how to filter the files, then use recursive copy: **`cp -R`**

Or you could just use `rsync` with `--prune-empty-dirs` option.

```
rsync --exclude='*xdir*' --prune-empty-dirs ~/dim_import ~/new
```

Note: If you don't use trailing slash from source (like above's example) `dim_import` is also copied.

Comment: I tried recursive copy, doesn't work how I want it.